# Excel Count specifc value across range of columns, but only once per column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have been trying to work out how to count the number of times a value appears across a range, but only once per column.

Using the example data below, the results I want to get to are shown in the end cells.  Using the **=COUNTIF(A3:G5,J3)** counts every time a name appears, causing double-ups on some days.

[image: example]

How can I make it count each name once per column, but across multiple columns (there would be 1 column for each day of the year in the real data)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also can count values using single array formula:

```
=SUM(--(MMULT(TRANSPOSE(--($A$2:$G$4=I2)),ROW($A$1:$A$3)^0)>0))
```

Array formula after editing is confirmed by pressing `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter`

[image]

Comment: WOW.  That is awesome.  It might be a silly question,  but why is the ROW a shorter range than the lit of people?  I ran a test and had the ROW as the the full list and it seemed to work, but just wanted to check.

Comment: @deaddingo This is because the ```MMULT``` function requires that the second range have as many rows as the first range columns. After ```TRANSPOSE``` range ```A2:G4``` becomes 3 columns x 7 rows, respectively the second argument must have three rows.

Answer (score 3):

in **A7** enter:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A3:A5,$J$3)>0,1,0)
```

and copy this across to **G7**.  then in **H7** enter:

```
=SUM(A7:G7)
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome.  This works perfectly and I would have never thought of doing it this way.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So the final question is 'count how many columns the name appears in'?

In which case you need a hidden row at the top or bottom of the sheet that contains everything in that column. Say it's row 1:

a) The formula in A1 would be `=CONCAT(A3:A5)`, B1 would be `=CONCAT(B3:B5)` and so on (where the range covers rows 3 to 5). CONCAT sticks text strings together.
b) the cell doing the counting would be `=COUNTIF(A1:G1, "*J3*")`. What that does is check which cells in A1:G1 contain J3 among other things.

And voila, problem solved.

Comment: @Garysstudent's answer works just as well - it's another way of summing up each column separately and then doing the overall count.